# JavaScript Objects - Object values getting undefined after constructing

Tags: javascript, function, object, methods

I am trying to  create an object that handles Google Maps Api as following:

```
function GoogleMap(container, mapOptions) {
    this.Container = container;
    this.Options = mapOptions;
    this.Map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(this.Container), this.Options);

    // Direction
    this.DirectionService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    this.DirectionRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    this.DirectionRenderer.setMap(this.Map);
    this.DirectionId = 0;
    this.DirectionResponse = new Array();
    this.DrawDirectionDriving = drawDirectionDriving;
}
```

and the drawDirectionDriving function is like this:

```
function drawDirectionDriving(start, end) {
  var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };

  this.DirectionService.route(request,
    function (response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        this.DirectionRenderer.setDirections(response);
        this.DirectionResponse[this.DirectionId] = response;
        this.DirectionId++;
      }
      else {
        alert("Error during drawing direction, Google is not responding...");
      }
    }
  );
}
```

and in somewhere, I am using the object like this:

```
var myGoogleMap;

function MapInit() {
    myGoogleMap = new GoogleMap("divMap", myMapOptions);
    myGoogleMap.DrawDirectionDriving("İstanbul", "Ankara");
}
```

The Google Map is shown on my browser, there is no problem in constructing the object but error in DrawDirectionDriving function.

When I create a breakpoint on this line: " myGoogleMap.DrawDirectionDriving("İstanbul", "Ankara");" the "DirectionRenderer" seems constructed, but after this line (after the "Draw" method) the DirectionRenderer object seems null (undefined) so it outs en error like this "couldn't get setDirections properties it is null bla bla..."

Could you please give me a hand?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I don't know the Google Maps api, but I can't see a return statement on the `drawDirectionDriving` function so presumably it's returning undefined, and anyway you're not using the new word with the `drawDirectionDriving` function so `this` isn't pointing to the `drawDirectionDriving` function.

Comment: My problem can be this which you are talking about but DrawDirectionDriving must be a method and can be wrong implemented. Is methods must be implemented like this or this is a type of variable assigning. Is it assign drawDirectionDriving's return value to DrawDirectionDriving variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) does point to something else in the `route` callback function. It's `DirectionRenderer` property resolves to `null`/`undefined`, and getting the `setDirections` property from that will cause the exception.

Use a dereferencing variable:

```
function drawDirectionDriving(start, end) {
  var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  var that = this;

  this.DirectionService.route(request,
    function (response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        that.DirectionRenderer.setDirections(response);
        that.DirectionResponse[this.DirectionId] = response;
        that.DirectionId++;
//      ^^^^ points to the GoogleMap instance
      }
      else {
        alert("Error during drawing direction, Google is not responding...");
      }
    }
  );
}
```